# Gradle build fails on Lombok annotated classes

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, jhipster, lombok

I have a JHipster project in which I have added dependency for Lombok in build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: lombok_version
```

And I have the Lombok plugin stalled for IntelliJ.  I've turned on annotation processing in IntelliJ, I can build without errors from the IntelliJ IDE, but when I try to build from the command line I get build errors.  It seems like Gradle is not processing the annotations and can't find the getter/setter and log declarations. The project also runs without any kind of errors.

Command Line:

```
./gradlew build
```

Errors :

```
/Users/.../source/v4.0/src/main/java/com/.../service/MyService.java:145: error: cannot find symbol
        log.info("Security Context: " + SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin());
        ^
  symbol:   variable log
  location: class MyService
```

Error:

```
/Users/.../source/v4.0/src/main/java/com/.../service/MyService.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
        myClass.setDescription(description);
                        ^
  symbol:   method setDescription(String)
  location: variable myClass of type MyClass
```

Service Class:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyService {      
    public void someMethod(){
        log.debug("Security Context: " + SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin());
        MyClass myCLass = new MyClass();
        myClass.setDescription(description);
    }
}
```

Entity Class:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="t_juror_file_update")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {

    private String description;

}
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, but totally stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your SecurityUtils class?

Comment: Did you also include a dependency on SLF4J?

Comment: Thanks Ethan and Roel for your responses.  I added more details to show I get compilation errors on getters/setters and log declarations.  I don't think it is specific to the SecureUtils class.  

I have a compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-logging' is providing SLF4J.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You will need to specify `lombok` as an annotation processor. To do this, You will need to add following to `build.gradle` in a `Jhipster` project.

```
apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt'

dependencies {    
    provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
    apt "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"

    /** ... */
}
```

`Jhipster` uses `net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin` for annotation processing.

For `IntelliJ` setup, `Enable annotation Processing` should be checked.

More Info: [Project Lombok - android instructions](https://projectlombok.org/setup/android.html)

Answer (score 111):

I had the same problem and worked for me when added to build.gradle:

```
dependencies{

compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'

}
```

Resource: https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Comment: works well with gradle 5.6.2, `annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'` is mandatory

Comment: In case you are using lombok in tests you need to add: `testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'` and `testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'`

Comment: Works like a charm! I only needed to add the `annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'` part to my existing `implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'` though. It's important to note that the version of the version of the annotationProcesser needs to match that of lombok though, or you'll get all sorts of other crazy errors. =^,~'=

Comment: It actually worked. I checked with gradle 7.6. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I use MacBook and Gradle 7.1.1. In the build.gradle file, I have added the following without a plugin then it can build successfully.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
}
```

Comment: That fixed for me, thanks!

Comment: For me, I ran into this issue when I migrated from mvn to gradle via the `./gradlew init` conversion

Answer (score 9):

For new users, consider using gradle plugin:

```
plugins {
  id "io.freefair.lombok" version "5.3.3.3"
}
```

Then you don't need `compileOnly` or `annotationProcessor`

Reference:
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.freefair.lombok

Answer (score 1):

The same issue i was facing where as ./gradlew  clean build were working fine but when i was trying  to do gradle clean build the getter and setter methods which is suppose to be generated by lombok where not found at the time of gradle build .
As it throw build failed exception for compilation

Earlier i was having grapper wrapper version 3.4.1 and gradle version 5.6.2.
So i am able to fix this issue by down grading my gradle version to 4.10.0
where as my gradle wrapper version remain the same i.e 3.4.1

This is the gradle version

### Gradle 4.10

Build time:   2018-08-27 18:35:06 UTC
Revision:     ee3751ed9f2034effc1f0072c2b2ee74b5dce67d

Kotlin DSL:   1.0-rc-3
Kotlin:       1.2.60
Groovy:       2.4.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.11 compiled on March 23 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_191 (Oracle Corporation 25.191-b12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64

### This is the gradle wrapper  version

### Gradle 3.4.1

Build time:   2017-03-03 19:45:41 UTC
Revision:     9eb76efdd3d034dc506c719dac2955efb5ff9a93

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_191 (Oracle Corporation 25.191-b12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64

This works for me

Comment: exactly the same problem. I don't think downgrading is an option.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Lombok dependencies were correctly added to the project, but the `build` task still failed. There were no useful clues in the output: every Lombok-generated method was marked with an unresolved reference error, and IDE had shown no errors whatsoever.

It turned out the issue was caused by using the experimental `@UtilityClass`. In particular, a `@UtilityClass`-annotated class used a static method import from another `@UtilityClass`-annotated class, none of which had the `static` modifier. Adding `static` to the imported method signature solved the issue.