# How to fix "lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor could not be initialized"

Tags: gradle, jhipster, lombok

My question relates to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236104/gradle-build-fails-on-lombok-annotated-classes".
I am using JHipster and Lombok 1.16.18 with `build.gradle`:

```
...
apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt'
...
dependencies {
    provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"
    apt "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"
}
...
```

but get the following error during compileJava:

```
warning: lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor could not be initialized. 
Lombok will not run during this compilation: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper$WrappedStandardJavaFileManager extends com.sun.tools.javac.api.ClientCodeWrapper$WrappedJavaFileManager implements javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager
```

The output is:

```
------------------------------------------------------------ Gradle 4.2.1 ------------------------------------------------------------ 
Build time: 2017-10-02 15:36:21 UTC 
Revision: a88ebd6be7840c2e59ae4782eb0f27fbe3405ddf 
Groovy: 2.4.12 
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015 JVM: 9.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 9.0.1+11) 
OS: Mac OS X 10.13.1 x86_64
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please edit your question and paste output of `gradlew -v`

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-10-02 15:36:21 UTC
Revision:     a88ebd6be7840c2e59ae4782eb0f27fbe3405ddf

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          9.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 9.0.1+11)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.1 x86_64

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73973709/6150881

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Output of `gradlew -v` shows that you are using JDK 9 which is not supported by JHipster 4.10.2, please use JDK 8. Same for [Lombok](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/985).

```
------------------------------------------------------------ Gradle 4.2.1 -------
Build time: 2017-10-02 15:36:21 UTC 
Revision: a88ebd6be7840c2e59ae4782eb0f27fbe3405ddf 
Groovy: 2.4.12 
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015 
JVM: 9.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 9.0.1+11) 
OS: Mac OS X 10.13.1 x86_64
```

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the similar warning in my project as we moved from JDK 8 to JDK 9.

Upgrading the lombok version helped me with removing the error.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I found the reference over here
https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1541

Comment: *Provide context for links*: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using gradle this has worked for me

```
dependencies {    annotationProcessor group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.18.16'}
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it turned out I was messing with my project setting and inadvertently set project JVM to 11, instead of the "correct" one, which was 8.

I reset it back to 8 and it's working again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have inserted the Lombok plugin inside the properties of maven.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.8</lombok.version>
</properties>
```

The above arrangement worked for me instead of adding the dependency as independent dependency.