# Lombok in project generated by Spring Initializr (LombokProcessor could not be initialized)

Tags: java, builder, lombok

I would like to create a class with **ownBuilderMethod** from Lombok. After click **Shift+F10** (launch app) I get the error:

```
Warning:(22, 8) java: lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor could not be initialized. Lombok will not run during this compilation: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.sun.tools.javac.main.DelegatingJavaFileManager$DelegatingSJFM extends com.sun.tools.javac.main.DelegatingJavaFileManager implements javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager
    (..)
```

And:

```
Error:(39, 19) java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class ProfileBuilder
location: class io.github.plkpiotr.fifabackend.model.Profile
```

Plain @Builder without this **builderMethodName** works properly, but with "ownBuilderMethod" doesn't.

Source code:

```
package io.github.plkpiotr.fifabackend.model;

import lombok.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "profiles")
@Data
@Builder(builderMethodName = "ownBuilderMethod")
//@AllArgsConstructor
//@NoArgsConstructor
public class Profile {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z]+(([',. -][a-zA-Z ])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$")
    private String nick;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Email
    private String email;

    public static ProfileBuilder builder() {
        return ownBuilderMethod()
                .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me. What version of Lombok are you using? What IDE are you using? What version of the Lombok plugin are you using? For me: Lombok 1.16.20, IntelliJ 2018.1, plugin 0.17-2018.1

Comment: Thanks for checking, but it still doesn't work for me.

IDE: IntelliJ 2018.IDEA 1.3

Lombok: 1.16.20

Plugin: 0.19-2018.1

Comment: The symbol its complaining about is the auto-generated builder name. Can you try overriding that and see if it makes a difference? Add `builderClassName = "Foo"` to the `@Builder` annotation, and change the return type of your `builder` method to `Foo`.

Comment: @Michael, What is your Java version? I have 10.
I remeber that my colleagues have similar problems with Java 9 and higher...

Comment: I'm using Java 8. Lombok 1.16.20 should work with Java 9, but not Java 10. You may have more success using an edge version of Lombok if you need to stay with Java 10.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Java 8 too, I checked in pom.xml -.-

Comment: I'm going to check annotation proccessors, but it is enabling.

Comment: Works for me too (IntelliJ 2018.1.5, Lombok 1.18.0, plugin 0.18-2018.1, Java 8). _Side note:_ Have you considered not generating `ownBuilderMethod` at all, and simply providing a custom builder method: `ProfileBuilder builder() { return new ProfileBuilder().id(UUID.randomUUID().toString()); }`?

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski The point is that Lombok's `@Builder` will always generate a `builder()` method unless you change the name, and OP wants `builder()` to return a builder with a pre-set ID. If he does what you suggest, Lombok will complain that a method with that signature is already defined.

Comment: I noticed warnings before error:
    Warning:(22, 8) java: lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor could not be initialized. Lombok will not run during this compilation: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.sun.tools.javac.main.DelegatingJavaFileManager$DelegatingSJFM extends com.sun.tools.javac.main.DelegatingJavaFileManager implements javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager (...)

Comment: @Michael Sorry, but you're wrong. See [Builder info](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder): _Each listed generated element will be silently skipped if that element already exists_. Or just give it a try :)

Comment: optional-true caused this...
`code <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
`
I wrote <version>1.16.22</version> instead of <optional> and everything works o.O

Comment: @plkpiotr You might want to update the question with the original Maven dependency config, and write an answer with the optional=true removed.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys :)
I've been participant of Forum Pasja Infromatyki so far, and I am still new here - so, thanks for your suggesting, Tomek ; )

Comment: Please do as Tomasz suggested so that this question can be useful to future readers. You should also consider using `@Builder.Default` on your ID field rather than overriding the `builder` method (you'll actually end up with 2 public builder methods, which might be confusing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the fact that LombokProcessor could not be initialized you have to change dependency of Lombok in Maven (pom.xml file):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

for:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

*This can also be cause by setting wrong SDK version.*

Checks todo:

- Enable annotation processing
- Set scope to provided for Lombok and remove optional tag
- Update Lombok version to latest ones
- Make sure you have right SDK project set in your IDE